# Ember.js: Call actions of ApplicationRoute from nested route

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

Let's say I have an `ApplicationRoute` with an action `goBack` (as you can see in the comment, I need to handle goBack by myself due to bugs in different mobile browsers):

```
Mobile.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend
    actions:
        goBack: ->
            # TODO: Remove when iOS 7 fixed their history
            # If there's no route to go back, go to front
            # TODO: Remove when Microsoft fixed their
            # back button in offline mode
            if not (Nn.MobileHelper.isiPhone() or Nn.MobileHelper.isIeMobile()) and @get("router.recentRoute")?
                return window.history.back()

            @get("controller").set("isHitBackButton", true)

            @transitionTo("front").then => @get("controller").set("isHitBackButton", false)
```

How can I trigger this action from another route? Note that since I need to call `@transitionTo`, this piece of code must be inside a route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actions bubble up to the application route by default!  Just use `{{action 'goBack'}}` in your template, or from code (minus components) call `this.send('goBack')`.  From components you need to wire up the event call a little different and use `this.sendAction('internalActionName')`.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ulIhUze/1/edit